# Validating arrays in an object of arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a query object that looks like this

```
{
"regions": [],
"countries": [],
"channels": [],
"partners": [],
"branches": [],
"agents": []
```

}

After populating the arrays in the object it looks like this.

```
{
    "regions": [{
        "key": "101",
        "value": "Middle East(XX)"
    }],
    "countries": [],
    "channels": [],
    "partners": [{
        "key": "201",
        "value": "Partner A"
    }, {
        "key": "202",
        "value": "Partner B"
    }],
    "branches": [{
        "key": "401",
        "value": "Bangalore"
    }, {
        "key": "402",
        "value": "Chennai"
    }],
    "agents": [{
        "key": "501",
        "value": "IBM - Metlife"
    }]
}
```

I'm trying to loop through each of these arrays and determine if I should show the filter component. If any of the arrays in the object holds value, I should be showing the filter component

The code:

```
case false:
  let itemsInQuery = 0;
  Object.keys(query).forEach((item) => {
  itemsInQuery = query[item].length ? itemsInQuery++ : itemsInQuery;
  })
  itemsInQuery ? this.setState({showBubbles: true, query}) : this.setState({showBubbles: false, query})
  break;
```

I'm not sure what is wrong here, but `itemsInQuery` is always zero. Also, is there a better way to do this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what is the case true?

Comment: try this `itemsInQuery += query[item].length ? 1:0`

Comment: true case code is out of context here and itemsInQuery variable exists only in the false case block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If any of the array have items in, you want a boolean to be true?

This sounds like a case for `.some` which on an array will take a predicate and return true if any item in that array matches the predicate.

```
const shouldShow = Object.keys(data).some(key => data[key].length > 0)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Comment: Thank you! Learnt a new method on the array object today :) Cheers!!

Comment: I'm assuming that the loop will come to an end as soon as atleast one of the array is non-empty

Comment: Yes, that is how `some` works: it stops iterating as soon as one callback returns a truthy value. You can even leave out the `> 0`.

Comment: Yes correct, it terminates as soon as it finds a true value. Leaving the > 0 is personal preference, I find it a little unreadable without, but whatever suits your style most!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this:

```
itemsInQuery = query[item].length ? itemsInQuery++
```

The `++` postfix operator returns the *current* value of `itemsInQuery` to the rest of the expression (i.e. 0) and then increments that variable to 1. But this is nullified by the assignment that happens *afterwards* to `itemsInQuery` which is the value 0.

So don't use `++` in an expression.

You can use this `+=` instead:

```
itemsInQuery += query[item].length ? 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```js
var data1 = {
    "regions": [{
        "key": "101",
        "value": "Middle East(XX)"
    }],
    "countries": [],
    "channels": [],
    "partners": [{
        "key": "201",
        "value": "Partner A"
    }, {
        "key": "202",
        "value": "Partner B"
    }],
    "branches": [{
        "key": "401",
        "value": "Bangalore"
    }, {
        "key": "402",
        "value": "Chennai"
    }],
    "agents": [{
        "key": "501",
        "value": "IBM - Metlife"
    }]
};

var data2 = {
  "regions": [],
  "countries": [],
  "channels": [],
  "partners": [],
  "branches": [],
  "agents": []
}

function hasEntries (data) {
  for (var index in data) {
    if (Array.isArray(data[index]) && data[index].length) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(hasEntries(data1));
console.log(hasEntries(data2));
```